# Type inference for "generic schema"

Tags: typescript, zod

I want to create a schema for HTML elements. The different elements can have input and output roles. For example, a `div` can have an output role, meaning that it can display some output. An `input` can have both input and output roles, meaning that it can be used to specify input and also display output.

If there are multiple elements with input role, they must have a key in order to distinguish the input values from each other. If there is only one element with input role, and it doesn't have a key, it must have a name (to be used in a HTML form). So we have three cases for the input role:

No input role, input role without key `{input: { name: string }}`, and input role with key: `{input: { key: string }}`.

For the output role, either all elements with the output role should have a key, or none of them should have it. This is because the output can just be a string that should be displayed in every element with output role (so no key is needed), or the output can be an object, and the key is used to select which part of the object to display in each element with output role. So we also have three cases for the output role:

No output role, output role without key: `{output: Record<string, never>}`, and output role with key: `{output: { key: string }}`.

I have created a Zod schema for the roles and a textarea. How can I get type safety, so that the correct type is inferred for the different specializations of `Textarea`? The expected inferred type for each specialization is shown at the bottom.

```js
import * as z from "zod";

const rolesSchema = <
  InputKey extends boolean | undefined,
  OutputKey extends boolean | undefined,
>(
  inputKey: InputKey,
  outputKey: OutputKey,
) => {
  return z.object(
    inputKey === undefined && outputKey === undefined
      ? {}
      : {
          roles: z
            .object(
              inputKey === undefined
                ? {}
                : {
                    input: z
                      .object(
                        inputKey
                          ? {
                              key: z.string(),
                            }
                          : {
                              name: z.string(),
                            },
                      )
                      .optional(),
                  },
            )
            .merge(
              z.object(
                outputKey === undefined
                  ? {}
                  : {
                      output: (outputKey
                        ? z.object({
                            key: z.string(),
                          })
                        : z.record(z.never())
                      ).optional(),
                    },
              ),
            )
            .optional(),
        },
  );
};

const textboxSchema = <
  InputKey extends boolean | undefined,
  OutputKey extends boolean | undefined,
>(
  inputKey: InputKey,
  outputKey: OutputKey,
) => {
  return z
    .object({
      type: z.literal("textbox"),
    })
    .merge(rolesSchema(inputKey, outputKey));
};

type Textbox<
  InputKey extends boolean | undefined,
  OutputKey extends boolean | undefined,
> = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof textboxSchema<InputKey, OutputKey>>>;

// Textbox<true, true>
type TextboxTrueTrue = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    input?: {
      key: string;
    };
    output?: {
      key: string;
    };
  };
};

// Textbox<true, false>
type TextboxTrueFalse = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    input?: {
      key: string;
    };
    output?: Record<string, never>;
  };
};

// Textbox<true, undefined>
type TextboxTrueUndefined = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    input?: {
      key: string;
    };
  };
};

// Textbox<false, true>
type TextboxFalseTrue = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    input?: {
      name: string;
    };
    output?: {
      key: string;
    };
  };
};

// Textbox<false, false>
type TextboxFalseFalse = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    input?: {
      name: string;
    };
    output?: Record<string, never>;
  };
};

// Textbox<false, undefined>
type TextboxFalseUndefined = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    input?: {
      name: string;
    };
  };
};

// Textbox<undefined, true>
type TextboxUndefinedTrue = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    output?: {
      key: string;
    };
  };
};

// Textbox<undefined, false>
type TextboxUndefinedFalse = {
  type: "textbox";
  roles?: {
    output?: Record<string, never>;
  };
};

// Textbox<undefined, undefined>
type TextboxUndefinedUndefined = {
  type: "textbox";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To preface this I'm not familiar with `zod` so this may not be as helpful as required. Also please correct me if I've made one (or likely many) mistakes.

On the typescript side you can use a conditional type to mimic the types you want.

Something like this:

```
type Textbox<
    InputKey extends boolean | undefined,
    OutputKey extends boolean | undefined,
> = {
    type: "textbox";
    roles?: {
        input?: InputKey extends true
            ? { key: string }
            : InputKey extends false
              ? { name: string }
              : undefined;
        output?: OutputKey extends true
            ? { key: string }
            : OutputKey extends false
              ? Record<string, never>
              : undefined;
    };
};
```

Then for the inference part I'm a little unclear what you need. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to add a comment first to clarify.

If you are **confident** in the object's type you could just cast it (`x as Textbox<true, undefined>`). If you need something more robust to determine the it's type you could write different type guards.

```
function isTextboxTrueFalse(obj: unknown): obj is Textbox<true, false> {
  const roles = (obj as Textbox<true, false>).roles;

  if (!roles) {
    return false;
  }

  const hasInputKey = 'input' in roles && 'key' in (roles?.input ?? {});
  const hasOutputKey = 'output' in roles && 'key' in (roles?.output ?? {});

  return hasInputKey && !hasOutputKey;
}
```